# "413 FULL head" error when sending a POST request

Tags: java, spring, rest, soapui

I have a Java application, hosted on Weblogic, which sends a REST POST request to a mock service hosted in SoapUI running on the same server.

The application gets as far as sending the request to the mock service via Spring's RestTemplate class before failing with a "413 FULL head" exception (org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException).

I have a Groovy script running on SoapUI which should log the headers that the request includes. If I send a POST request to the mock service from within SoapUI itself, the headers are printed by the script successfully. When the Java application sends a (failed) request, no headers are printed. This would would imply that the request is failing before the script is executed.

I am not sure how else I can identify what headers the POST request includes.

Looking on here, it seems like a lot of other times this issue has been reported is when using GET requests. I am definitely using a POST for this request.

Java: 1.7.0_02

Spring: 4.1.7

SoapUI: 5.2.1

Weblogic: 10.3.6.0

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: The fact that you get a good response when you send POST from SoapUI suggests that the java application may not be sending a POST, perhaps due to some configuration error. Maybe you can use a sniffer to verify? Or maybe set up an Apache server and turn on logging, the response will be 404 but the access logs will mention the method

Comment: I'm pretty sure a POST request is sent from Java - in the code, the request is initiated via the exchange() method which takes the HTTP method as a parameter. I have traced the code and am pretty certain that I set it to be HttpMethod.POST.

I will investigate how to intercept the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the TCP/IP Monitor in Eclipse to find that the "Accept-Charset" HTTP header included a large amount of data.

This was fixed by setting the writeAcceptCharset property on the StringHttpMessageConverter which was used by the Spring RestTemplate object.

The issue and solution is described here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7316.